# CSS Toggle not floating on right side

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-float, responsive

Okay, so I am trying to make a responsive navigation menu for my website. I am currently having trouble making this dang float property work. So I've taken a combination of https://www.w3schools.com/ and a YouTube tutorial to make a website that I envision.

Here is what I got so far (*Link to my code is below in hyperlink to JS Fiddle*)

https://jsfiddle.net/dcannon96/e9mgsLqd/

So if you actually look in the label attribute under the media and screen section where the max-width begins for pixels.

Take a look at this part of my **CSS.**

```
label {
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   /* float: right; */
}
```

My goal is to make my top nav bar menu to appear beneath the hamburger icon when in mobile/tablet form. When in desktop mode, my menu list is on the left side of the screen, but when I am in mobile, the float right **DOES NOT** bring the rest of the items beneath the top nav bar.

This is what I'm trying to do https://youtu.be/xMTs8tAapnQ?t=611 (*video skips to 10 minute and 11 seconds in*)

So you can see what I am talking about once you remove the /**/ comment from the float right and see the different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `overflow:hidden` to the menu so the top nav bar menu to appear beneath the hamburger icon
see this https://jsfiddle.net/dow2qLck/1/

```
.menu {
overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
display: none;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks man! Every damn time! I've keep telling everyone! There is always that one sneaky line of code that just solves the damn problem! You sir deserve a cookie!

Answer (score 0):

hi I uncommented the `float:right` property of .label and it was aligned to right.. Hope this what you're looking for. thanks

visit below link
https://jsfiddle.net/dow2qLck/1/`777`

Comment: Noticed the different image here in the screenshot. So for the first link [Screenshot 1](https://imgur.com/iBadirP) which looks a bit of odd as to how it is style in the second link and the second link here [Screenshot 2](https://imgur.com/ROCaYwA). Which is how I want it to look but with the toggle icon to be located on the right instead of the left.